# Express validator - how to allow optional fields

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am using express-validator version 2.3.0. It appears that fields are always required

```
req.check('notexist', 'This failed').isInt();
```

Will always fail - broken or am I missing something? There is a `notEmpty` method for required fields which seems to indicate the default is optional but I am not able to get the above to pass.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use the `optional` method:

```
req.check('notexist', 'This works').optional().isInt();
```

This won't work if the field is an empty string `""` or `false` or `0` for that you need to pass in `checkFalsy: true`
`.optional({checkFalsy: true})`

An `422 status` error will be thrown if you are only using `.optional()` & not passing any arguments.

**Edit:** [See the docs here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions)

Comment: Where is this documented?
Edit: Here https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions

Answer (score 30):

As for `express-validator 6` it's done like this:

```
check('email').isEmail().optional({nullable: true})
```

From documentation:

> You can customize this behavior by passing an object with the
> following options:
>
> **nullable:** if true, fields with null values will be considered optional
>
> **checkFalsy:** if true, fields with falsy values (eg "", 0, false, null)
> will also be considered optional

More info about [optional rule](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions).

Comment: I assume that for most cases people need empty string "" to be optional. Therefore, use `check("field").optional({nullable: true, checkFalsy: true});`.

Comment: should `.optional()` be added at the beginning or end of the chain of all the checks?

Comment: It doesn't matter @FedericoCapaldo

Answer (score 4):

That's the expected behavior, yes. The assumption of validation is that you want to act on a value of a known key. To get what you want, you could do something like this:

```
if(req.param('mykey'))
  req.check('mykey', 'This failed').isInt();
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `notEmpty()`?

Comment: `notEmpty` is just checking the length of the string that is the param value. So 'this' passes, but '' fails.

Comment: It might have been added to the API after this comment but the .optional() method works very well.

Comment: You can't do this in the latest version where you're supposed to declare the validators as middleware